# Indirect modification of overloaded element of Google_Service_YouTube_InvideoPromotion has no effect

Tags: php, youtube-api

I tried to change the type from video to associate website along youtube channel update API but custom text only updated.  I got the Notice error

```
try{

$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['type'] = 'website';
$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['websiteUrl'] ='http://myassociatewebsite.com/';
$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['customMessage'] = 'Update tex1';

$updateResponse = $youtube->channels->update('invideoPromotion', $responseChannel);
 }catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
  $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}

How to fix that issue please confirm it?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is exact update code to update the items

```
$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['id']['type'] = 'website';
$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['id']['websiteUrl'] = 'http://yourassiociatewebsiteurl';
$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['customMessage'] = 'Click here';
$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['timing']['type']= 'offsetFromStart';
$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['timing']['offsetMs']= 100;
$responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['timing']['durationMs']= 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issues as stated above, here's how I managed to make it work:

```
if( !empty($responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items']) ){
    // This part did not work for me, that's probably because the channel does not have any InvideoPromotion setup yet
    $responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['id']['type'] = 'video';
    $responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['id']['videoId'] = $video_id;
    $responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['customMessage'] = 'Click here';
    $responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['timing']['type']= 'offsetFromStart';
    $responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['timing']['offsetMs']= 100;
    $responseChannel['invideoPromotion']['items'][0]['timing']['durationMs']= 10000;
}else{
    $invideoPromo = new Google_Service_YouTube_InvideoPromotion();
    $ivP_items[] = array(
        'id' => array(
            'type' => 'video',
            'videoId' => $video_id
         ),
        'timing' => array(
            'type' => 'offsetFromStart',
            'offsetMs' => 100,
            'durationMs' => 10000
        )
    );
    $invideoPromo->setItems($ivP_items);

    $responseChannel['invideoPromotion'] = $invideoPromo;
}
```

Hope that helps...